# Cypress cy.visit does not send cookies with request

Tags: cookies, cypress

I ran into a weird behaviour when running `Cypress` tests. It seems like `cy.visit()` fails to send cookies with the request.

First of all, yes, in `cypress/supports/index.js` I have set:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: 'token'
})
```

And in my test I do the following:

```
it('test', () => {
  cy.logIn()
  cy.getCookie('token').then(console.log)
  cy.visit('/')
  // verify that the user is redirected to /home, which it isn't...
})
```

To log the user in, I run my custom `logIn()` command, which successfully logs the user in. Upon doing so, the application sets a cookie named `token` with the session token. Then I `console.log` the cookie successfully just before calling `cy.visit()`. However, my backend receives a request with no cookies and therefore does not perform a redirect as expected...

Has anyone run into something similar? Any ideas what may be happening?

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with the same problem.
My cookie was set with the `secure: true` flag.
After setting it to `secure: false` (Only in the Testing-Environment) the cookie was successfully sent to Cypress.

Comment: I'm testing a production build Remix application in GitHub Workflows and this fixed my issue of Cypress not sending the login cookie with the requests. I wish I could upvote this more.

Answer (score 2):

In my application I have been setting cookies with the following properties:

```
sameSite: 'none',
secure: true
```

`@Develrockment`'s suggestion to set `secure: false` is probably correct, only in my case the application failed to set the tokens altogether, because there's a [requirement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) for `secure` to be `true` if `sameSite` is `none`, which would`ve required me to conditionally change both values.

Instead, this was a good opportunity to review my sameSite approach and set its value by default to `lax` (which most browsers apparently use by default anyway), which solved my issue with Cypress tests.

Answer (score 0):

Set the secure attribute in application propreties to false and it will be fixed

Comment: Isn’t this what @develerockment’s existing answer already suggests?